# Display particular (dynamicaly) URL without parent folder. Leave The Others Alone

Tags: .htaccess, url, hyperlink, uri

I started learning rewrites today

First of all here are examples of my links

```
Index.php?action=pictures
Index.php?action=pictures&type=kitchen
Index.php?action=pictures&type=ceiling
Index.php?action=services
Index.php?action=services&type=shower
Index.php?action=services&type=windows
```

In my `.htaccess` file I have this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Do not Rewrite files or folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1 [L]

#Ordinary
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ .htaccess [F]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ Index.php?action=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ Index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

Rewrites URLs to

```
localhost/pictures
localhost/pictures/kitchen
localhost/pictures/ceiling

localhost/services
localhost/services/shower
localhost/services/windows

//etc
```

I like to have ALL my links working as is with an exception of services where I don't need parent folder `/services/`.
Result:

```
localhost/pictures
localhost/pictures/kitchen
localhost/pictures/ceiling

localhost/services
localhost/shower
localhost/window
```

I tried to rewrite .htaccess but either I get only parentfolder to work or only subfolder.
I tried to add this but I do understand that this matches everything...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ Index.php?action=services&type=$1 [L]
```

I can however hardcode it like this

```
RewriteRule ^window/?$ Index.php?action=services&type=window [L]
```

Would like to have something dynamical. If folder services -> show no folder yet still be able to see `localhost/services!`
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: How would Apache know if a particular string is an action, or a type of service?

Well, you have three options:

- We hardcode the types of services. Anything that does not match a type must be an action.
- We hardcode the actions. Anything that does not match an action must thus be a type of service.
- Apache has no way of knowing: We feed it to a script, who might be able to do some magic to find out what this string is.

In your case hardcoding the actions seems like the best idea, at least when the actions are static.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ Index.php?action=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(pictures|services)/?$ Index.php?action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ Index.php?action=services&type=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Your solution is better. looks like there is no other way then hardcode.